# Access hash values in java to create objects

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, hashmap

I get parameters from such URL

```
http://localhost:8080/Server/file?fileid=34&userid=admin&token=rdfcgvhb34567DFGHJK&firstname=alex&lastname=ozouf&age=33&firstname=kevin&lastname=gerfild&age=27
```

I get the fieid, userid and the token values by @QueryParam(fileid)...
Then I don't know how much parameters are in the URL, so I get the rest the rest of the values by

```
@Context UriInfo uriInfo
String query = uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery().toLowerCase();
final Map<String, List<String>> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
final String[] pairs = query.split("&");
for (String pair : pairs) {
    final int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
    final String key = idx > 0 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8") : pair;
    if (!query_pairs.containsKey(key)) {
        query_pairs.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
    final String value = idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8") : null;
    query_pairs.get(key).add(value);

}
System.out.println(query_pairs);
```

This is how the result looks like

```
{fileid=[34], userid=[admin], token=[rdfcgvhb34567dfghjk], firstname=[alex, kevin], lastname=[ozouf, gerfild], age=[33, 27]}
```

I already have the fileid, userid, toekn parameters. Now I want to create an array with instances of The rest parameters. I have a class Person who has a firstname, lastname and age as attributes. I want to do something like

```
List<Person> l = new ArrayList<>();
for (i=0, **every item in query_pairs**)
    l.add(new Person(firstname[i], lastname[i], age[i]));
```

How can I get this "every item in query_pairs" and how can I access values like firstname[i]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
for (i=0; i < query_pairs.get("firstname").size(); i++) {

    l.add(new Person(query_pairs.get("firstname").get(i), query_pairs.get("lasttname").get(i), query_pairs.get("age").get(i));

}
```

Comment: I get an error "Type mysmatch, cannot convert from int to boolean", in query_pairs.get("firstname").size()

Comment: Thank you but now I get a NullPointerException